# Error_Redshift_SQL

Tags: sql, boolean, amazon-redshift

Getting below error while executing a query with 'IF' Boolean in Redshift while able to run in HeidiSQL.

Query -

```
if ((a.L_ASSIGNED_TO <> 'xxxx' AND b.LS_NAME IN ('xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx')),'A2',
if ((b.LS_NAME = 'xxxx' AND a.L_ASSIGNED_TO <> 'xxxx' AND a.L_ASSIGNED_TO <> '' AND a.L_ASSIGNED_TO <> 'NA'),'A2','')) AS A2_Status,
if ((a.L_ASSIGNED_TO <> 'xxxx' AND b.LS_NAME IN('xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx')),'A1',
if ((b.LS_NAME = 'xxxx' AND a.L_ASSIGNED_TO <> 'xxxx' AND a.L_ASSIGNED_TO <> '' AND a.L_ASSIGNED_TO <> 'NA'),'A1',
```

Error-

SQL Error [500310] [42883]: Amazon Invalid operation: function if(boolean, "unknown", "unknown") does not exist;

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show us the code that raises the exception.

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: What is the DBMS behind your HeidiSQL? because it looks like the `IF` statement has you wrote it does not exist. So should use `CASE` or `IF Bool THEN ** ELSE` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into map this to DECODE() statements (a form of a CASE statement that is more readable in these structures).

```
DECODE(<boolean expression>, true, <value if true>, <value if false>)
```

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DECODE_expression.html